# Can this form be filled and submitted using python's responses module?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, jupyter-lab

I am writing a data scraping script. It's purpose is to collect data on available broadband deals from BT's website. I cannot figure out why my simple requests code doesn't fill in the form and follow through to the next page.

Please help me figure out how to enter data into this form and save the output html for data scraping.

I have identified the relevant tags in the form that I am interested in. I am trying to populate the UPRN field and continue to the next page

Link to website: https://www.dslchecker.bt.com/#

My python code:
'''python

```
import requests
url = "https://www.dslchecker.bt.com/#"
payload = {'UPRN':'10033360983'}
r = requests.post(url, data = payload)
print(r.text)
```

'''

Form from the website:

'''html

```
<form method="post" action="adsl/ADSLChecker.UPRNoutput"><input type="hidden" name="URL"> <input value="a%20service%20provider" type="hidden" name="SP_NAME">
      <span class="subheading">UPRN:</span><br><input maxlength="13" size="14" name="UPRN" autocomplete="off" style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAPhJREFUOBHlU70KgzAQPlMhEvoQTg6OPoOjT+JWOnRqkUKHgqWP4OQbOPokTk6OTkVULNSLVc62oJmbIdzd95NcuGjX2/3YVI/Ts+t0WLE2ut5xsQ0O+90F6UxFjAI8qNcEGONia08e6MNONYwCS7EQAizLmtGUDEzTBNd1fxsYhjEBnHPQNG3KKTYV34F8ec/zwHEciOMYyrIE3/ehKAqIoggo9inGXKmFXwbyBkmSQJqmUNe15IRhCG3byphitm1/eUzDM4qR0TTNjEixGdAnSi3keS5vSk2UDKqqgizLqB4YzvassiKhGtZ/jDMtLOnHz7TE+yf8BaDZXA509yeBAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;"> <input value="56" type="hidden" name="VERSION"> <input value="E" type="hidden" name="MS"> <input value="no" type="hidden" name="CAP"> <input value="Y" type="hidden" name="AEA"> &nbsp; <input class="form_button" value="submit" type="submit"> </form>
```

'''

Please follow this link :https://www.dslchecker.bt.com/# and enter 10033346575 in the UPRN field to see the desired output

My output when ran in a jupyter notebook:

'''html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<!-- saved from url=(0063)http://dslcheckerait.vade.bt.com:61065/adsl/adslchecker.welcome -->
<HTML><HEAD>
<STYLE>
.body {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #004d5f; FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
.bodybold {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #333333; FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
.errormessage {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 11px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
.formDescription {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 9px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
.form_button {BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #666666 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #6400AA; FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Calibri Light, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-SIZE: 10px; BORDER-TOP: #666666 1px solid; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
.heading {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #004d5f; FONT-SIZE: 14px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
.heading3 {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #333333; FONT-SIZE: 10px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
.heading4 {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #91b1b8; FONT-SIZE: 10px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
.subheading {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Calibri Light, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: color: #333333; FONT-SIZE: 14px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
A:active {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Calibri Light, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #6400AA; FONT-SIZE: 12px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: underline
}
A:hover {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Calibri Light, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #6400AA; FONT-SIZE: 12px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: underline
}
A:link {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Calibri Light, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #6400AA; FONT-SIZE: 12px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
A:visited {FONT-VARIANT: normal; FONT-FAMILY: Calibri Light, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #6400AA; FONT-SIZE: 12px; FONT-WEIGHT: bold; TEXT-DECORATION: underline
}
BODY {PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; MARGIN: 10px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; PADDING-TOP: 0px
}

</STYLE>

<TITLE>BT Broadband</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type><LINK
rel=stylesheet type=text/css
href="adslchecker_font.html">
<META content=text/css http-equiv=Content-Style-Type><META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
<SCRIPT>
<!--
function setFocus() {
    document.forms[0].elements[2].focus();
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>

<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.7601.18751"></HEAD>
<BODY onload=setFocus()>
<TABLE width=500 align=center>
  <TBODY>
  <TR>
    <TD>
      <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>  var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;var EnableRightClick = 0;if(isNS) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);function mischandler(){if(EnableRightClick==1){ return true;}else {return false; }}function mousehandler(e){  if(EnableRightClick==1){ return true; }  var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;  var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;  if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;}function keyhandler(e) {var myevent = (isNS) ? e : window.event;if (myevent.keyCode==96)EnableRightClick = 1;return;}document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;document.onkeypress = keyhandler;document.onmousedown = mousehandlerdocument.onmouseup = mousehandler;</SCRIPT>

      <TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%"><!-- Start Header -->
        <TBODY>
        <TR><BR><BR>
          <!--<TD height=20 vAlign=top align=left><IMG border=0 alt="BT Wholesale"
            src="dsl_images/g_main_logo.gif" width=129
height=20></TD></TR>
        <TR>
          <TD class=body height=14 vAlign=top align=left><IMG alt=""
            src="dsl_images/spacer.gif" width=450 height=14></TD></TR>
        <TR>//-->
          <TD class=body vAlign=top align=left fontStyle="italic">
            <TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width=450><!-- Start Page Title -->
              <TBODY>
              <TR>
                <TD height=45 vAlign=top width=600 align=left><FONT
                  style="FONT-FAMILY: Calibri Light" color=#6400AA size=6.5><B> BT BROADBAND
                  AVAILABILITY
              CHECKER</B></FONT></TD></TR><!-- End Page Title --></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><SPAN
      class=body><!--RESPONSE-START-->
      <P><SPAN class=body><font size="2" font face="Calibri Light" color="#333333">Welcome to the Broadband Availability checker. This
      will provide a provisional check of your ability to receive reliable
      Broadband services.</font></SPAN></P>
      <P><SPAN class=body><font size="2" font face="Calibri Light" color="#333333">Please enter your telephone number.</font></SPAN></P>
      <FORM method=post action=adsl/adslchecker.TelephoneNumberOutput><INPUT
      type=hidden name=URL> <INPUT value=a%20service%20provider type=hidden
      name=SP_NAME> <SPAN class=subheading>TELEPHONE:</SPAN><BR><INPUT
      maxLength=14 size=14 name=TelNo> <INPUT value=56 type=hidden name=VERSION>
      <INPUT value=E type=hidden name=MS> <INPUT value=no type=hidden name=CAP>
      <INPUT value=Y type=hidden name=AEA> &nbsp; <INPUT class=form_button value=submit type=submit> </FORM>
      <P><SPAN class=body>Or</SPAN></P>
      <P><SPAN class=body><font size="2" font face="Calibri Light" color="#333333">Please enter your access line id.</font></SPAN></P>
      <FORM method=post action=adsl/adslchecker.AccessLineIDOutput><INPUT type=hidden
      name=URL> <INPUT value=a%20service%20provider type=hidden name=SP_NAME>
      <SPAN class=subheading>ACCESS LINE ID:</SPAN><BR><INPUT maxLength=13
      size=14 name=ALID> <INPUT value=56 type=hidden name=VERSION> <INPUT
      value=E type=hidden name=MS> <INPUT value=no type=hidden name=CAP> <INPUT
      value=Y type=hidden name=AEA> &nbsp; <INPUT class=form_button value=submit type=submit> </FORM>
          <P><SPAN class=body>Or</SPAN></P>
      <P><SPAN class=body><font size="2" font face="Calibri Light" color="#333333">Please enter your UPRN.</font></SPAN></P>
      <FORM method=post action=adsl/ADSLChecker.UPRNoutput><INPUT type=hidden
      name=URL> <INPUT value=a%20service%20provider type=hidden name=SP_NAME>
      <SPAN class=subheading>UPRN:</SPAN><BR><INPUT maxLength=13
      size=14 name=UPRN> <INPUT value=56 type=hidden name=VERSION> <INPUT
      value=E type=hidden name=MS> <INPUT value=no type=hidden name=CAP> <INPUT
      value=Y type=hidden name=AEA> &nbsp; <INPUT class=form_button value=submit type=submit> </FORM>
      <P><SPAN class=body><font size="2" font face="Calibri Light" color="#333333">If you do not have a telephone number or access line
      id, please select the</font>
<TABLE>
  <TR>
   <FORM method=post action=adsl/adslchecker.address>
          <INPUT value="" type=hidden name=url>
          <INPUT value=a%20service%20provider type=hidden name=SP_NAME>
          <INPUT value=56 type=hidden name=VERSION>
          <INPUT value=E type=hidden name=MS>
          <INPUT value=no type=hidden name=CAP>
          <INPUT value=Y type=hidden name=AEA>
          <TD><A href=# onclick="document.forms[3].submit()">Address Checker</A></TD>
   </FORM>
          <FONT>
          <TH><P><SPAN class=body><font size="2" font face="Calibri Light" color="#333333">or the</font></SPAN></P></TH>
          </FONT>
   <FORM method=post action=adsl/adslchecker.postcode>
          <TD><A href=# onclick="document.forms[4].submit()">Postcode Checker</A></TD>
          <INPUT value="" type=hidden name=url>
          <INPUT value=a%20service%20provider type=hidden name=SP_NAME>
          <INPUT value=56 type=hidden name=VERSION>
          <INPUT value=E type=hidden name=MS>
          <INPUT value=no type=hidden name=CAP>
          <INPUT value=Y type=hidden name=AEA>
   </FORM>
          <FONT>
          <TH><P><SPAN class=body><font size="2" font face="Calibri Light" color="#333333">or the</font></SPAN></P></TH>
          </FONT>
   <FORM method=post action=adsl/adslchecker.bbeuidform>
          <TD><A href=# onclick="document.forms[5].submit()">BBEU Checker</A></TD>
          <INPUT value="" type=hidden name=url>
          <INPUT value=a%20service%20provider type=hidden name=SP_NAME>
          <INPUT value=56 type=hidden name=VERSION>
          <INPUT value=E type=hidden name=MS>
          <INPUT value=no type=hidden name=CAP>
          <INPUT value=Y type=hidden name=AEA>
   </FORM>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<P><SPAN class=body><font size="2" font face="Calibri Light" color="#333333">By submitting a query into this checker you accept <A
      href="https://www.btwholesale.com/pages/static/terms-of-use.htm" target="_blank">Terms of Use</A> for this checker.</font>
<!--RESPONSE-END--></SPAN></P></SPAN></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></BODY></HTML>
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So 1) you're posting to the wrong URL.

From the return HTML, the "action" for the form you want is "adsl/ADSLChecker.UPRNoutput"

2) there are hidden fields in the form you're not submitting

```
<form method="post" action="adsl/ADSLChecker.UPRNoutput">
    <input type="hidden" name="URL"> 
    <input value="a%20service%20provider" type="hidden" name="SP_NAME">
    <span class="subheading">UPRN:</span><br>
    <input maxlength="13" size="14" name="UPRN"> 
    <input value="56" type="hidden" name="VERSION"> 
    <input value="E" type="hidden" name="MS"> 
    <input value="no" type="hidden" name="CAP"> 
    <input value="Y" type="hidden" name="AEA"> &nbsp; 
    <input class="form_button" value="submit" type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Try:

```
payload = { 
    "UPRN": "10033360983", 
    "SP_NAME": "a%20service%20provider", 
    "VERSION": "56", 
    "MS": "E", 
    "CAP": "no", 
    "AEA": "Y" 
}   
url = 'https://www.dslchecker.bt.com/adsl/ADSLChecker.UPRNoutput'
r = requests.post(url, data = payload)
```

Comment: You are also beautiful! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are posting the the wrong url. I used pandas to pull the table, so you'll need to do a little clean up work, but try:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.dslchecker.bt.com/adsl/ADSLChecker.UPRNoutput'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}

UPRN = 10033346575


payload = {
'URL': '',
'SP_NAME': 'a%20service%20provider',
'UPRN': str(UPRN),
'VERSION': '56',
'MS': 'E',
'CAP': 'no',
'AEA': 'Y'}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

tables = pd.read_html(response.text)
df = tables[-1]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
          Featured Products  Downstream Line Rate(Mbps)                              Upstream Line Rate(Mbps)                           Downstream Handback Threshold(Mbps)  WBC FTTC Availability Date WBC SOGEA Availability Date Unnamed: 8_level_0
         Unnamed: 0_level_1                        High                         Low                      High                       Low                  Unnamed: 5_level_1          Unnamed: 6_level_1          Unnamed: 7_level_1 Unnamed: 8_level_1
0      VDSL Range A (Clean)                           3                         1.2                       1.2                       0.8                                 0.8                   Available                   Available                NaN
1   VDSL Range B (Impacted)                         2.8                         1.2                       1.2                       0.5                                 0.8                   Available                   Available                NaN
2         Featured Products  Downstream Line Rate(Mbps)  Downstream Line Rate(Mbps)  Upstream Line Rate(Mbps)  Upstream Line Rate(Mbps)              Downstream Range(Mbps)  WBC FTTP Availability Date                         NaN                NaN
3            FTTP on Demand                         330                         330                        30                        30                                  --                   Available                          --                NaN
4             ADSL Products  Downstream Line Rate(Mbps)  Downstream Line Rate(Mbps)  Upstream Line Rate(Mbps)  Upstream Line Rate(Mbps)              Downstream Range(Mbps)           Availability Date                         NaN                NaN
5               WBC ADSL 2+                     Up to 1                     Up to 1                        --                        --                            1 to 3.5                   Available                          --                NaN
6                  ADSL Max                     Up to 1                     Up to 1                        --                        --                         0.75 to 2.5                   Available                          --                NaN
7            WBC Fixed Rate                         0.5                         0.5                        --                        --                                  --                   Available                          --                NaN
8                Fixed Rate                         0.5                         0.5                        --                        --                                  --                   Available                          --                NaN
9           Observed Speeds                        VDSL                        VDSL                       NaN                       NaN                                 NaN                         NaN                         NaN                NaN
10          Other Offerings                         NaN                         NaN                       NaN                       NaN                                 NaN           Availability Date                         NaN                NaN
11           VDSL Multicast                          --                          --                        --                        --                                  --                   Available                          --                NaN
12           ADSL Multicast                          --                          --                        --                        --                                  --                   Available                          --                NaN
```